How to set the click event of each item in a ContextMenuStrip, whether root or children, all sub-items to a sub-item. By Recursion method
With this method, I collect all the ContextMenuStrip events and use them in a subroutine.
I have created a code to generate a click event for the root and all sub-branches inside the ContextMenuStrip. Can this code be the answer or not?
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
     ' Create the ContextMenuStrip
     Dim contextMenu As New ContextMenuStrip()
     ' Create top-level menu items
     Dim item1 As New ToolStripMenuItem("Item 1")
     Dim item2 As New ToolStripMenuItem("Item 2")
     Dim subItem1 As New ToolStripMenuItem("Sub Item 1")
     Dim subItem2 As New ToolStripMenuItem("Sub Item 2")
     ' Create third-level subitems
      Dim subSubItem1 As New ToolStripMenuItem("Sub Sub Item 1")
      Dim subSubItem2 As New ToolStripMenuItem("Sub Sub Item 2")
     ' Create fourth-level subitems
     Dim subSubSubItem1 As New ToolStripMenuItem("Sub Sub Sub Item 1")
     Dim subSubSubItem2 As New ToolStripMenuItem("Sub Sub Sub Item 2")
    ' Build the hierarchy
     subSubItem1.DropDownItems.Add(subSubSubItem1)
     subSubItem1.DropDownItems.Add(subSubSubItem2)
     subItem1.DropDownItems.Add(subSubItem1)
     item1.DropDownItems.Add(subItem1)
     item1.DropDownItems.Add(subItem2)
     contextMenu.Items.Add(item1)
     contextMenu.Items.Add(item2)
     ' Now you can associate this ContextMenuStrip with a control
      Me.ContextMenuStrip = contextMenu
     AnyItemToClickEvent(contextMenu.Items)
    End Sub

Public Sub AnyItemToClickEvent(Items As ToolStripItemCollection)
    For Each itm As ToolStripItem In Items
        AddHandler itm.Click, AddressOf ContextMenuClick
        Dim subItems As ToolStripMenuItem = TryCast(itm, ToolStripMenuItem)
        AnyItemToClickEvent(subItems.DropDown.Items)
    Next
End Sub 

'Result Event
Private Sub ContextMenuClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim clickedItem As ToolStripMenuItem = CType(sender, ToolStripMenuItem)
    ' You can add your logic here to handle the click event
     MessageBox.Show("You clicked: " & clickedItem.Text)
End Sub


Seems like it would make more sense to handle the ItemClicked event of the ContextMenuStrip itself.
